# how to read header data with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to read values from header url in javascript?

For example if I have something like:

```
www.something.com/details.html?test=something
```

I need to be able to read this data when I redirect to page `details.html`.

What would be a good approach for this? Maybe adding some php code to get data?

Comment: Is the javascript running on details.html?

Comment: What do you mean with header? The querystring?

Comment: @JacobParker yes Javascript is running on details.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about getting the value from a get variable and using it in javascript? If so I've used something similar to this before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction(){
     var value = "<?php echo $_GET['test']; ?>"
}
</script>
```

And it's worked beautifully for me.